# This matrix result confuse me by strange float display: "0. "

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, return

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQdxk.png)

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "./A.csv";
A = pd.read_csv(path).values;

tposeA = np.transpose(A);
normA = LA.norm(A);

X0 = tposeA / ((normA)**2)

print(X0)
```

I have been working on this piece and it returns strange result in the matrix, do anyone know what this means?
Many thanks!!

```
[First col and 4th row]

[0.0089  0.0035  0.0017  0.0053]
 
[0.0035  0.0089  0.0035  0.0089]
 
[0.0035  0.0178  0.0106  0.0124]
 
[0.(blank)  0.0017  0.0124  0.0267]
```

Comment: [ask] how would we know what exactly is confusing to you? I see nothing confusing here.

Comment: The value is 0. The decimal indicates it's floating point. What's the question?

Comment: Ah silly me! Sorry for bothering u. Thank u so much!!! Gonna delete the post after this comment!!

Comment: That's how NumPy displays floating-point 0. That's it. The value is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking at floating point numbers, `0.` means that the number equals exactly zero. It is the way NumPy displays float.